# jQuery element.dispatchEvent() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the Lighbox feature of JQuery on an Image Slider. The Image Slider is working absolutely fine, but when I click on the image to view the Image in the Lightbox, then its opening as a simple Image, rather than opening in the lightbox. On Inspecting the element with Firebug, I am getting the following error:-

```
element = [Document gallery.html]
eventName = "dom:loaded"
memo = undefined
_methodized()prototype.js (line 246)
fireContentLoadedEvent()
```

Comment: prototype.js is being used by the Lightbox as a javascript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery lightbox feature sometimes clashes with other libraries that you are using in your page. For more details you can visit the following link: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/